# google sheets how to refresh worksheet that refers to other worksheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a rather large Google Sheets document with 10-20 people contributing content to about 300-400 worksheets, and I created an aggregate worksheets that uses INDIRECT() to look at the content of other worksheets and add it to the aggregate worksheet. The aggregate table has formulas like the one below:

```
=TRANSPOSE(INDIRECT(A626&"!A1:Y19", TRUE))
```

where A626 contains a text field with the same name as one of the worksheets that different users can create and edit.

The aggregate worksheet has about 300 of these calls, and it iterates through them printing the content blocks of the worksheets in aggregative fashion from top to bottom.

The aggregate worksheet has a Timestamp cell on top that I added after reading on this site that it would ensure it updates every so often:

```
=TEXT(NOW(), "HH:mm:ss")
```

Currently, what I observe is that the aggregate worksheet does not update on a consistent manner: sometimes it seems to be hours behind, sometimes days behind updating the content on the other worksheets.

It also seems that when nobody has the worksheet open (night time), the timestamp does not update. But it seems like when the timestamp updates in the aggregate worksheet, it's still not a guarantee that the rest of the content will update.

How can I ensure the aggregate worksheet either passively updates every X hours or actively updates by clicking refresh or other means?

Comment: Maybe because I'm testing with small data but I am not able to reproduce the issue. NOW() is a volatile function and should update anytime the Aggregate worksheet is updated. I tested INDIRECT (), INDEX(), and IMPORTRANGE(). All tests positively changed the timestamp. If changes are indeed being made and the timestamp is not reflecting the changes in a 'timely' manner then maybe it's the size of the data?? I don't know. If that is the issue, perhaps you can try a Time-driven trigger via Apps Script - https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers